# How can an organization maintain an atmosphere of zero bullying?

Tags: bullying

Workplace bullying by co-workers is a very common problem in a workplace.

It is a pervasive problem in India.

What specific policy can an organization adopt to maintain zero office bullying?

Comment: This must come from above, especially in a hierarchical system. There must be people that listen and act upon bullying complaints. And people who understand what bullying is (and what it is not).

Comment: Zero bullying? Shut down the org. Unless it is a small or, thre is no way to ensure that. The best policies in the world will not stop the occasional bullying to happen, mostly because the higher ups will only ever hear of it after the fact. What can a shop chain do to ensure zero theft? Same answer. Get realistic.

Comment: Keep in mind that not everybody realises they're actually bullying on the workplace. When confronted they will often reply with "We were just joking around with him/her...."

Comment: @Daniel, "Yes. And, according to our regulations, joking is considered as bullying if the subject complains. So, this is your dismissal letter. Coz, you have done this 'joking' for the 3rd time. Bye bye!"

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Kilisi, what do you think?

Comment: I think it's a homework question :) The only solution is zero tolerance as Joe suggests but that is fraught with so many problems and open to abuse  in so many ways that it's not realistic.

Comment: I suppose we can phase out the human part of human resources, which is of course the biggest point of vulnerability, but beyond that there is no "specific policy" that can even approach zero bullying. That should not in itself be a goal anyway, a sensible approach to *dealing with and responding to bullying* is what can be talked about. But even that is likely well outside this site's scope. VTC too broad.

Comment: in india it is pervasive proglem? Indians are so nice people. I cant imagine it doing so. There is even a stand up comedy about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu_m5diSk4k

Comment: @Will_create_nick_later, That balloon guy isn't even an Indian in that he knows nothing. I am not talking about Indians living in USA. I am talking about Indians living in India. To know Indians better, you need to travel to India more than once, and have a business or job India. As an intro, watch the movie "Rocket Singh: Salesman of the Year" (2009) to get a taste of the Indian workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What specific policy can an organization adopt to maintain zero office bullying?

Put up posters with the following:

- Employees who engage in bullying will be fired.
- Employees who fail to report bullying will be fired.

And do not be soft on the follow through!

Comment: For company it might be not profitable to do so, so they might not accept this. Maybe those bullies are making profit. Of course thats sad, but for company what cares is profit as first priority.

Comment: @Will_create_nick_later Sure, but that's nothing to do with the question asked, which assumes that you want to cut out bullying and asks how to go about doing it in practice. How to get a company that doesn't want a zero-tolerance policy towards bullying to adopt one anyways is a different question (and, of course, probably the answer is you can't).

Answer (score 2):

Eliminating bullying is a worthy goal. Your organization needs policies which define bullying (listing types of behavior that will not be tolerated), outline the steps for making a complaint, and address how complaints will be handled and resolved (including at what point a person will be dismissed).

In addition, you should do staff trainings on bullying and harassment so people understand what it is, how it impacts others and the organization, and how it will be handled going forward.

Success is completely dependent on your willingness to follow your own anti-bullying policy.

Good luck!